# display value in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

this is my current situation. if i code like below it will never display because it get no value.

```
<% int z = 0;
    int count = 3 
        do { %><% z++;} <c:if test="${not empty array[z]}">
                       <td width="50%" height="15px">${array[z]}</td>
                     </c:if>  while (z < count);%>
```

i tried to code like this (hardcode,replace z with 0), it will display record.

```
<% int z = 0;
    int count = 3 
        do { %><% z++;} <c:if test="${not empty array[0]}">
                       <td width="50%" height="15px">${array[0]}</td>
                     </c:if>  while (0 < count);%>
```

perhaps can you guys guide me on how to make it read z value but not read it as z only. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Does that even compile? You're going into scriptlet mode and add tags there, which shouldn't compile since tags are no Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use c:set for the variable z or set it to pageContext

```
<% 
    int z = 0;
    int count = 3 
    do {  
      z++; 
      pageContext.setAttribute("z", z);
      %>
      <c:if test="${not empty array[z]}">
        <td width="50%" height="15px">${array[z]}</td>
      </c:if>
      <%}while (z < count);
%>
```

Comment: your way solved my problem but now facing when the loop come to z=1 it get null. i will check my jsp thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get your tags right try to do the test in Java code and render the cell only if this is true:

```
<% 
int z = 0;
int count = 3;
do {  
  z++;
  if( array[z] != null ) { //you might have to do additional checks here
   %>
   <td width="50%" height="15px"><%=array[z]%></td>
   <%
  }
} 
while (z < count);
%>
```

Alternatively you might try to use `${not empty array[<%=z%>]}` etc. but I'm not sure here since we rarely use scriptlets.

As a second alternative try to use `<c:forEach>` which is much cleaner IMHO:

```
<c:forEach var="z" begin="1" end="${count}">
   <c:if test="${not empty array[z]}">
      <td width="50%" height="15px">${array[z]}</td>
   </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i tried with ${not empty array[<%=z%>]} and ${not empty array[<=z%>]} before posting this ......both not working.....

Comment: @FruitLai hmm, that's what I wasn't sure about. Please have a look at the second alternative to your code I posted, since this should be easier to understand and make for cleaner code (if it fits your needs).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<% int z = 0;
   int count = 3 
   do { 
      if (!array.isEmpty()) {
      %>
      <td width="50%" height="15px"><%=array[z]%></td>
 <%while(z < count)%>
```